# Batch: unknown filename into variable to import it later into db2 table

Tags: batch-file, db2

Simple thing I want to do, but it doesn't work since the filename is not found:

I have a .txt file with an unknown filename that will be later imported into a db2 table.

I was thinking about using something like this:

```
SET FILEDIR=\\FileServer\TestDir  
SET FILE=%FILEDIR%\*.txt

db2 -wz%LOG% import from %FILE% of del method p(....) insert into tablename (.......)
```

When I try to run the batch, the file is not read since the `syntax for the filename [..] is wrong`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET FILEDIR=\\FileServer\TestDir  
rem SET FILE=%FILEDIR%\*.txt
for %%# in ("\\FileServer\TestDir\*.txt") do set "file=%%#"

db2 -wz%LOG% import from %FILE% of del method p(....) insert into tablename (.......)
```

eventually you'll need to map the network drive if nothing is found.